# get name attribute inside a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Is there anyway to get the name attribute inside a while loop after I click a submit button so I will be able insert it to my database?

```
<tbody>
<?php
    include('includes/dbconn.php');
    $get_name= "SELECT tech_id, tech_name FROM technology";

    if($display_name=$conn->query($get_name)){
        while($row=$display_name->fetch_assoc()){
            $app_id=$row['tech_id'];
            $app_name=$row['tech_name'];
            ?>
            <tr> 
                <td id="app_name"><?php echo $app_name; ?> </td>
                <td> <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $app_id; ?>" value="P0"> </td>
                <td> <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $app_id; ?>" value="P1"> </td>
                <td> <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $app_id; ?>" value="P2"> </td>
                <td> <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $app_id; ?>" value="P3"> </td>
                <td> <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $app_id; ?>" value="P4"> </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        $display_name->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: You can use JS/Jquery to get the value of name attr and submit the data using AJAX.

Comment: `name` will the the array key in the get\post array

Comment: as long as the inputs are within a <form> tag, you can inspect the $_POST/$_GET var after form submission to find out what element was clicked

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in lots of different ways. However, let me give you an example, so you can understand the fundamentals and apply it in your example above.

Lets say you need to submit values of individual records to the back end server. In the example below, you will have set of input fields and a submit button next to it. Every time you press the submit button, the `name` and `value` get sent to the server (using `jQuery Ajax`). So, you do your logic there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
    <body>
        <?php
           $html = '';      
           $array = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');
           foreach ($array as $elem) {
               $name = 'name_' . $elem;
               $value = 'value_' . $elem;
               $html .= '<input type="text" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value .'" /> <button type="button"  onclick="submitFunc(\''.$name.'\',\''.$value.'\')">Submit</button> <br/>';        
           }
           echo $html;     
        ?>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function submitFunc(name, value) {          
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {name : name, value: value},
                  url: "your_server_side_file.php",           
                  success: function(res){

                  },
                  error: function(res) {

                  }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask questions if you need any further clarifications.